# $\log^2_{\frac{2}{3}}x+\log^2_{\frac{2}{3}}y-\log^2_{\frac{2}{3}}(x+y)=1$and$\log_{\frac{3}{2}}x*\log_{\frac{3}{2}}y -\log_{\frac{3}{2}}(x+y)=0$

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations

$\log^2_{\frac{2}{3}}x + \log^2_{\frac{2}{3}}y - \log^2_{\frac{2}{3}}(x+y) = 1$ and $\log_{\frac{3}{2}}x * \log_{\frac{3}{2}}y - \log_{\frac{3}{2}}(x+y)=0$

I turn all logarithms to base $\frac{3}{2}$
Then I multiply second equation by two and sum equations
I got $\log^2_{\frac{3}{2}}xy = \log^2_{\frac{2}{3}}(2/3 * (x + y))$
Then I tried to replace $ x + y $ with $\frac{3}{2}xy$ but I failed. 
$a = \log_{\frac{3}{2}}x$ $ b = \log_{\frac{3}{2}}y
$

$a^2 + b^2 = (a+b+1)^2+1$ and $ab + a + b + 1 = 0 $
After all recalculations I am still getting Wrong answer. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Is the last $y$ in both equations added by itself, not inside a logarithm? Or do you have logarithms of $x+y$ as the last (third) term in both equations? If the latter is the case, then please correct the error in how you typed your question.

Comment: Ok, y is inside logarithm

Comment: Is your first equation written correctly? As is this
$$\log^2_{\frac{2}{3}}x + \log^2_{\frac{2}{3}}y - \log^2_{\frac{2}{3}}x+y = 1$$
becomes
$$ \log^2_{\frac{2}{3}}y+y = 1$$

Comment: I fixed it, y is inside logarithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\log^2_{\frac{2}{3}}x + \log^2_{\frac{2}{3}}y - \log^2_{\frac{2}{3}}(x+y) = 1$

$\log_{\frac{2}{3}}x=-\log_{\frac32}x$

$\log^2_{\frac{3}{2}}x + \log^2_{\frac{3}{2}}y - \log^2_{\frac{3}{2}}(x+y) = 1\quad(*)$

$\log_{\frac{3}{2}}x \cdot \log_{\frac{3}{2}}y -\log_{\frac{3}{2}}(x+y)=0$

$\log_{\frac{3}{2}}(x+y)=\log_{\frac{3}{2}}x \cdot \log_{\frac{3}{2}}y\quad(\times)$

plug into $(*)$

$\log^2_{\frac{3}{2}}x + \log^2_{\frac{3}{2}}y - \log^2_{\frac{3}{2}}x \cdot \log^2_{\frac{3}{2}}y= 1$

$\log^2_{\frac{3}{2}}x \left(1-\log^2_{\frac{3}{2}}y\right)=1-\log^2_{\frac{3}{2}}y$

$\log^2_{\frac{3}{2}}x= 1\to \log_{\frac{3}{2}}x= \pm 1\to x_1=\frac32;\;x_2=\frac23$

$1-\log^2_{\frac{3}{2}}y=0\to \log_{\frac{3}{2}}y=\pm 1\to y_1=\frac32;\;y_2=\frac23$

Recall $(\times)$ if $x=\frac23$

$\log_{\frac{3}{2}}(\frac23+y)=\log_{\frac{3}{2}}\frac23 \cdot \log_{\frac{3}{2}}y$

$\log_{\frac{3}{2}}(\frac23+y)=- \log_{\frac{3}{2}}y$

$\log_{\frac{3}{2}}(\frac23+y)= \log_{\frac{3}{2}}\frac{1}{y}$

$\frac23+y=\frac{1}{y}\to y=\frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt{10}-1\right)$ negative solution must be rejected

in a similar way we see that $x=\frac32$ leads to

$\log_{\frac{3}{2}}(\frac32+y)= \log_{\frac{3}{2}}y$

$\frac32+y=y$ impossible

then we have $y=\frac23$ if we do the same steps we get

$x=\frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt{10}-1\right)$

summarizing the solutions are two

$$\color{red}{x_1=\frac23;\;y_1=\frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt{10}-1\right)}$$
$$\color{red}{x_2=\frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt{10}-1\right);\;y_2=\frac23}$$

Hope this can be useful

Comment: I also get these answers, but did you check it?$ \log^2_{\frac{3}{2}} (6/4) > 7$

Comment: @Cheburek I have edited and everything is OK now. Nice problem... just lose half an hour because equations were wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

If we let $a=\log_{\frac{3}{2}}x$ and $b=\log_{\frac{3}{2}}y$, then we have
$$\log_{\frac{2}{3}}x=-a \text{ and } \log_{\frac{2}{3}}y=-b,$$
also let $c=\log_{\frac{3}{2}}(x+y)$, then we reach to equations
$$ab=c \text{ and } a^2+b^2=1+c^2 $$